# Sorting a list of favourites by pairwise comparison

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, quicksort

I'm trying to make a program (in Flutter, but that doesn't really matter) to rank your favorites by comparing two at a time (Kind of like [this](https://jesseepinkman.tumblr.com/evermoresort), but without "I like both" and "I don't care"), but right now **a lot** more comparisons than expected are necessary.

I'm currently using the Quicksort algorithm based on code I found on the [Swedish Wikipedia](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#C-kod). The list is in the correct order after sorting but almost 10 times as many comparisons are required to get there compared to the sorter I mentioned above. And compared to the [minimum required comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list), I need about 6 times more comparisons.

This is my current code:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List list = [];
  List<List> compared = [];
  int n = 0;
  Random rand = Random();

  swapItems(int low, int high) {
    int tmp = list[low];
    list[low] = list[high];
    list[high] = tmp;
  }

  // Check of the element with index low is higher than the element with
  // index high.
  //
  // This will be replaced with a user input later (Two buttons).
  compare(low, high) {
    n++;
    return list[low] > list[high];
  }

  partioning(int low, int high) {
    if (low >= high) {
      // Abort if the list is less than 2 items.
      return;
    }

    // If the list consists of two elements, compare them and swap if required.
    if (high - low == 1) {
      if (compare(low, high)) {
        swapItems(low, high);
      }
      return;
    }

    // Pivot element.
    int pivot = high;
    int i, j;

    // Loop until all elements in the first part (before where i and j stops) of
    // the list is lower than those in the upper part.
    do {
      // Move indexes towards pivot element.
      i = low;
      j = high;

      // Increase lower index until an element that is higher than the pivot
      // element is found.
      while ((i < j) && !compare(i, pivot)) {
        i++;
      }

      // Decrease upper index until an element that is lower than the pivot
      // element is found.
      while ((j > i) && compare(j, pivot)) {
        j--;
      }

      // Swap items if i is less than j. (They could be the same as the pivot
      // element and thus each other). Since the while loops moves until an
      // element that is higher respectively lower than the pivot element,it is
      // guaranteed that they will be in the wrong order comapred to each other.
      if (i < j) {
        swapItems(i, j);
      }
    } while (i < j);

    // Swap the element at the index where i and j stops with the pivot element
    // since the pivot element will be lowest element.
    swapItems(i, pivot);

    // Sort the parts above and below i recursively. Start with the smallest.
    if ((i - low) < (high - i)) {
      partioning(low, i - 1);
      partioning(i + 1, high);
    } else {
      partioning(i + 1, high);
      partioning(low, i - 1);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(onPressed: null),
                RaisedButton(onPressed: null),
              ],
            ),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              n = 0;
              list = List.generate(17, (_) => rand.nextInt(10000));
              partioning(0, list.length - 1);
              print(n);
              print(list);
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Have I done an error when converting the C code on Wikipedia to dart, or is the code that inefficient from the beginning? Or is there another algorithm that would be better in this case, and that other similar sorters online use?

Comment: [Bottom-up heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Bottom-up_heapsort) does ~ `n log_2 n` comparisons on average, which is optimal; its worst case is `1.5 n log_2 n`.

Comment: Why are you implementing quicksort yourself anyway instead of using [`List.sort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sort.html)?

Comment: I need user input on each comparison. I don't know how I would do that with List.sort

Comment: `List.sort` takes a comparison callback.  How is that different?

Comment: Well, I did not think of that... But it's still not as good as the first link in my comment unfortunately.

Comment: I was able to see the source code for the website in the first link by using the inspector (Everything including the JavaScript is in one HTML file) so i know how that algorithm works now, and it looks like the merge sort algorithm is being used. Flutter has a function called [`mergeSort`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/mergeSort.html), and using that I get results that are almost as good as the first link I shared.